# AngularJS: How to apply sort/reverse-sort to table in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have HTML part as shown below. I am populating header with ng-repeat and also can add header by button. If anyone can please help me in how to sort and reverse-sort data by clicking on table columns. I can only make single property working at a time either add column by button or sorting data.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newColumn" placeholder="Add Column Name">
<button class="btn-cstm" ng-click="addColumn()">Add Column</button>

<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-click="sortBy(column)">    {{column}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:propertyName:reverse">
        <td ng-repeat="entry in entries">{{row[entry]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My Controller is as:

```
$scope.columns = [];
$scope.rows = [];
$scope.entries = [];
$scope.newColumn = " ";
$scope.addColumn = function() {
    var counter = $scope.columns.length + 1;
    $scope.columns.push($scope.newColumn + counter);
};
var dataContainer = [
    {name: 'John',   phone: '555-1212',  age: 10},
    {name: 'Mary',   phone: '555-9876',  age: 19},
    {name: 'Mike',   phone: '555-4321',  age: 21},
    {name: 'Adam',   phone: '555-5678',  age: 35},
    {name: 'Julie',  phone: '555-8765',  age: 29}
];
angular.forEach(dataContainer, function (values) {
    $scope.rows.push(values)
});
$scope.container = {
    name: "Name",
    phone: "Phone Number",
    age: "Age"
};
angular.forEach($scope.container, function (values, keys) {
    $scope.columns.push(values);
    $scope.entries.push(keys);
});

$scope.propertyName = 'name';
$scope.reverse = true;
$scope.dataContainer = dataContainer;
$scope.sortBy = function (propertyName) {
    $scope.reverse = ($scope.propertyName === propertyName) ?     !$scope.reverse : false;
        $scope.propertyName = propertyName;
}
```

Here is my approach to sort data property working correctly.
change in the controller:

Replace

```
 angular.forEach($scope.container, function (values, keys) {
    $scope.columns.push(values);
    $scope.entries.push(keys);
});
```

with

```
$scope.columns = $scope.container;
```

Change in HTML:
replace

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-click="sortBy(column)">{{column}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:propertyName:reverse">
        <td ng-repeat="entry in entries">{{row[entry]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in columns" ng-click="sortBy(key)">{{value}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:propertyName:reverse">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in columns">{{row[key]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But then addColumn is not working since I am not populating table by pushing into column array. If anyone can help me in this, I will appriciate your time.